# Как произвести импорт из MySQL в PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, django

Суть такова:
Есть сайт на Django+PostgreSQL, есть дамп базы этого же сайта, только с MySQL. Нужно как-то переместить информацию из дампа на сайт с постгресом.

Comment: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Converting_MySQL_to_PostgreSQL раздел Convert and Import. Обратить внимание на необходимую замену символов

Comment: спасибо, я прочитал, но у меня нет возможности сделать совместимый дамп.
Зато появился еще один архив, в котором в xml-файлах лежит информация для каждого django-приложения. Это может быть как-то полезно?

Answer (score 1):

Можете попробовать воспользоваться утилитой [taps](https://github.com/ricardochimal/taps). [Taps for Easy Database Transfers](http://adam.heroku.com/past/2009/2/11/taps_for_easy_database_transfers/).

Либо экспортировать данные из MySQL в [фикстуры](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/howto/initial-data/#providing-initial-data-with-fixtures), а затем загрузить фикстуры в Postgres.